# PHP PDO function lastInsertId and race condition

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Suppose that in my system an user **U1** create a new database entry in table **A** and I use **lastInsertId** function to get the ID (auto_increment field) of such entry, but almost at the same time (a little later) another user **U2** do the same.

In this case, does **lastInsertId** return for **U1** the ID of the entry added by the other user, since it is the most recent?

Thanks.

Comment: Answer in here valid for your question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371306/best-way-to-find-the-last-inserted-id-in-mysql-using-php

Comment: My understanding is that each user will be on a different connection so there's no problem. At the start of your script when you create a connection, you're essentially creating it for just that 1 run of your code. Another user will have a new connection unless you do some fancy stuff to share the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should only worry about race conditions in case your using a single connection for different threads. If your using a different connection for each request, you should be fine. Checkout http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html for more details.

Comment: You basically have to go out of your way to re-use your connection across your threads, so unless you did something like that, then it is ok.